# Использование данных из xml как ключ ассоциативного массива

Tags: php, xml

Есть такой xml документ:

```
 <Domains>
        <DomainData IsValid="true">
            <DomainName>mozilla.com</DomainName>
            <Values>
                <Data>
                    <Parameter>Cy</Parameter>
                    <Value xsi:type="CyApiData">
                        <Cy>12000</Cy>
                        <Yaca>0</Yaca>
                        <YaBarMirrow>0</YaBarMirrow>
                    </Value>
                </Data>
            </Values>
        </DomainData>
```

А вот пример из официальной документации api, который я использую, но в самом нижнем цикле немного изменен, чтобы записывать нужные мне данные в ассоциативный массив (домен = тиц).

```
foreach($sessionData->Domains->DomainData as $domain)
    {
        // Доменное имя
        echo $domain->DomainName."<br/>";
        $str = $domain->DomainName;     
        foreach($domain->Values->Data as $data)
        {
            echo $data->Parameter."<br/>";
            echo $data->Value."<br/>";

            foreach(get_object_vars($data->Value) as $paramKey => $paramValue)
            {
                //echo "{$paramKey} = {$paramValue}"."<br/>";
                if( stristr($paramKey,"cy") )
                {
                    //$out_array["domain"][] = $domain->DomainName;
                    //$out_array["domain"]["cy"][] = $paramValue;
                    $out_array[$str][] = $paramValue;
                }


            }
        }
        echo "<br/>";
```

Но почему-то все время получаю ошибку и пустой массив на выходе:

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\w\functions\domain.php on line 1
19
```

Этот элемент, вроде, строковый, но, видимо, это не так на деле, поэтому интерпретатор ругается. В чем может быть дело и как правильно записать данные в массив?

UPD: Мне уже подсказали, нужно:

```
$str = $domain->DomainName->__toString();
```

Только я не понял, почему так. Если `$domain->DomainName` — это не строка, а объект, то почему он выводится через echo?

Понятно, он неявно преобразуется в строку. Вопрос решен!

Comment: Что еще за официальная документация? К чему? Откуда взялось `$session` внезапно? А кто такой `ТИЦ`? И почему у вас тег не закрытый у `<Domains>`?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, это кусок xml документа (он верный). Я имел в виду официальную документацию апи, который я использую.

Comment: нужно закрывать тег, чтоб не сбивать с толку, иначе получается ошибка может быть из-за нее.... Также нужно бы показать что за документацию и к чему вы используете. А без нее - все равно что в телепатов играть. Черт её знает почему у вас такая ошибка....а еще хорошо бы посмотреть полный кусок кода, что вы там делаете и загружаете.... может еще на той стадии проблемы

Comment: разве итерацию нужно делать не по `Domains`?

Comment: Ваш код в принципе не рабочий, а ошибка указывает на то, что в `foreach` передали значение без возможности итерации

Comment: `echo` преобразует объект в строку через магический метод  `__toString`

Comment: @Invision, код рабочий. А ошибка была в $out_array[$str], потому что $str был объектом а не строкой.

Comment: У автора ошибка сыпалась на `functions\domain.php on line 1` насколько я понял предоставленный код  и есть из `domain.php`. Главное разобрались.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переписал ваш код

```
<?php
$xmlData = '
         <Domains>
            <DomainData IsValid="true">
                <DomainName>mozilla.com</DomainName>
                <Values>
                    <Data>
                        <Parameter>Cy</Parameter>
                        <Value xsi:type="CyApiData">
                            <Cy>12000</Cy>
                            <Yaca>0</Yaca>
                            <YaBarMirrow>0</YaBarMirrow>
                        </Value>
                    </Data>
                </Values>
            </DomainData>
        </Domains>';

$domains = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlData);
$out_array = array();
foreach ($domains as $domain) {
    // Доменное имя
    $str = (string) $domain->DomainName;
    foreach($domain->Values as $value)
    {
        $data = $value->Data;
        foreach($data->Value->attributes() as $paramKey => $paramValue)
        {
            if( stristr($paramValue,"cy") )
            {
                $out_array["domain"][] = $str;
                $out_array["domain"]["cy"][] = (string) $paramValue;
            }


        }
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}

print_r($out_array);
```

Получаем:

```
Array
(
    [domain] => Array
        (
            [0] => mozilla.com
            [cy] => Array
                (
                    [0] => CyApiData
                )

        )

)
```

Дальше реализуйте исходя из ваших требований